# spring-retry: is it safe to wait for long periods? (half hour, etc.)

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-retry

I have a web app, in which I am using `spring-amqp` to listen for a message in `rabbitmq` with retry enabled with the following settings:

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    listener:
      simple:
        retry:
          enabled: true
          multiplier: 2
          initial-interval: 15m
          max-interval: 1h
```

Where the `org.springframework.retry.backoff.Sleeper` most used implementation is based on `Thread.sleep` which - *AFAIK* - locks the current thread?

I found that concurrent `amqp` listener count by default is 1, even if I changed it 10 for example; the thread pool would lose a thread for a long period.

Is it safe to wait for long periods with `spring-retry`, *in terms of blocking threads from the listener thread pool for long periods*?

It is a case by case issue, or it is a best practice not to use long intervals to avoid thread blocking?

Comment: Safe in what respect? It depends on the application. Yes; the thread sleeps during the back off.

Comment: @GaryRussell I've edited the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your application and what is causing the retry. If, say, a database is not available then it is likely all threads will go into retry anyway.

If, however, some types of messages might succeed while others are in these long waits, then perhaps your design needs to be revisited and use different queues/listener containers for the two message types.

It won't really "hurt" anything, but I am not really a fan of leaving messages in an unack'd state for long periods. It might be better to `stop()` the listener container until the downstream problem is resolved.